# How to receive the max value for each day of a mont?

Tags: php, mysql

i would like to receive the max value for each day of the month but my request doesn t work as i want .Can you hep me to do it . thanks

```
$chartQuery = "SELECT max(TmpExt) AS tmpMax , date_format(Date,'%d/%m %y ') AS datum  
FROM DAVIS  group by TmpExt,Date";
```

[image]

Comment: Does Date column also have time? Nevertheless, if you want to group only by Date, you shouldn't add other columns in the group by. Remove TmpExt from the group by. If Date column also has time, you'll need to group by the datepart only (`group by date(Date)` or `group by datum` (you can use alias in the group by) or `group by 2` (group by the second column))

Answer (score 1):

You should be aggregating by the date alone:

```sql
SELECT MAX(TmpExt) AS tmpMax, DATE_FORMAT(Date, '%d/%m %y') AS datum  
FROM DAVIS
GROUP BY Date;
```

Comment: possibly Date is a datetime or timestamp, and you'd want to `GROUP BY DATE(Date)`

Comment: DATE(date) was the soution. Thanks a lot ;)

Comment: If green checkmark to the left be possible it would be nice.